# How to Save an image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I use the below command to display the image

```
imshow(img,[]);
```

when i use the following command to save the image it is saved as an empty white page

```
imsave;
```

how to save the image in this case any command would do

Comment: or else `imsave(img)`

Answer (score 1):

Convert image data into an actual image and try again:

```
h = image(img); %Convert to object
imsave(h); %Save image object
```

Notice that if you close the figure window generated by `image()`, the object is deleted and the handle has will point to nothing. Though this may be beyond of what you are asking for.

Hope this adjustment solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into an issue with matrix type and range. If `img` is type `double` it needs to be scaled between 0 and 1.

A common issue is to load an image in `uint8` (scaled between 0 and 255), convert to `double` in order to do some processing on it, without scaling, and then try and save it out. When you do that, MATLAB tries to convert back to `uint8`, and any values in the image outside the [0 1] range are clipped. On many images this means that the file comes out all white.

To get around this, use functions like `im2double` and `im2uint8` rather than just `double` or `uint8` when converting images.

Try at the command line the difference between:

```
img = imread('pout.tif');
img = double(img);
imshow(img,[]);
imsave;
```

and

```
img = imread('pout.tif');
img = im2double(img);
imshow(img,[]);
imsave;
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert the image to rgb using

```
img1=label2rgb(img);
```

then again convert the image into an gray image using

```
img2=rgb2gray(img1);
```

then u can use imshow to show the image and save it using imsave

```
imshow(img2);
imsave();
```