# Matlab move multiple files in a directory

Tags: matlab, directory, filenames, subdirectory, movefile

Using Matlab, I want to move the images present in the same directory in two new directories according to their name.

In the directory there are two set of image' name: 'neg-0.pgm', 'neg-1.pgm', 'neg-2.pgm', ... and 'pos-0.pgm', 'pos-1.pgm', 'pos-2.pgm', ...

I tried different functions to change the image directory but I wasn't able to make the operation successfully.

My code is:

```
if not(exist('./CarDataset/TrainImages/PosImages', 'dir'))
    mkdir ./CarDataset/TrainImages PosImages
end

if not(exist('./CarDataset/TrainImages/NegImages', 'dir'))
    mkdir ./CarDataset/TrainImages NegImages
end

trainIm = dir('./CarDataset/TrainImages/*.pgm');

for i = 1:size(trainIm, 1)
    if(strcmp(trainIm(i).name, 'neg*.pgm'))
        save(fullfile('./CarDataset/TrainImages/NegImages', ['neg-' num2str(i) '.pgm']))
    end
end
```

I don't get any error but the new directories are still empty.

Comment: `if contains( trainIm(i).name, 'neg' )`, with an `else` for everything else?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error? The new directories are not created? The images are not saved? Which part of your code works and which one not?

Comment: @RobertoT I don't get any error and the directories are created correctly but the images are not saved in them.

Comment: Never tried to use `save` to save an actual image, only matrixes or structs. Maybe you should try other ways instead of that function. Possible ways: https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/23481-how-to-save-image
 & 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344884/how-to-save-an-image-in-matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are two issues going on:

1 - using `strcmp` in the if statement with a wildcard (*) may not work properly

2 - use `movefile` instead of `save`.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html

See below code (use after you have made the new directories):

```
    origDir = './CarDataset/TrainImages/';
    trainIm = dir([origDir '*.pgm']);
    
    for i = 1:size(trainIm, 1)
        origFile = trainIm(i).name;
        if contains(trainIm(i).name, 'neg'))
             newDir = './CarDataset/TrainImages/NegImages/';
        else
             newDir = './CarDataset/TrainImages/PosImages/';
        end
        movefile([origDir trainIm(i).name], newDir);
    end
```